# Using Google Maps API to determine Longitude/Latitude for an address

Tags: google-maps

I have a script which uses Google Maps to determine Longitude/Latitude for a list of 3000+ addresses. It was written several years ago, and appears to no longer work. It sends requests to a URL similar to this one (using a Key I had registered):

http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?output=xml&key=123456

When I load the URL in my browser, I get a message "We're sorry but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now."

I think maybe that API is outdated. Digging around, I found this API which I believe is more current:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=true&key=123456&address=address+goes+here

When I plug in my Key I get a message "Request Denied. The provided API key is invalid."

So maybe I just need a new Key? I am not entirely sure that what I am trying to do requires a Key at all, but if it does, I don't know which API to register.

I logged into Google, then created a new API Project. I need to add Services to my Project. There are a list of Services related to maps, here are a couple I was looking at:

Google Maps Coordinate API
Courtesy limit: 1,000 requests/day

Google Maps Geolocation API
Courtesy limit: 0 requests/day • Pricing

Google Maps JavaScript API v3
Courtesy limit: 25,000 requests/day • Pricing

If all I want to do is retrieve Longitude/Latitude, what is my best option?

Would appreciate any assistance navigating the Google maze of APIs. Thank you!

Comment: [**As it's documented**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#api_key) you'll only need to activate the service **Geocoding API**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some time ago i used the [google maps web API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/) to get longitude/latitude via url request.
I don't know how they feel about that number of requests, but it worked without any registration.
You want to use the [google maps geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) to get longitude/latitude. There you find everything about the request syntax etc.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @HeidiSalami answer: Parsing the results using the the Deserialize method allows you to better manipulate the data:

```
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    GeoLocation GoogleGeoLocation = (GeoLocation)serializer.Deserialize(ResponseforGoogleMaps, typeof(GeoLocation));
```

**GeoLocation class**

*Take note that the different names should match those in the results provided (currently that are all lower case)*

```
    public class GeoLocation
    {
        public List<result> results { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
    }

    public class result
    {
        public List<address_component> address_components { get; set; }
        public string formatted_address { get; set; }
        public geometry geometry { get; set; }
        public string place_id { get; set; }
        public string[] types { get; set; }

    }
    public class address_component
    {
        public string long_name { get; set; }
        public string short_name { get; set; }
        public string[] types { get; set; }
    }
    public class geometry
    {
        public gviewport bounds { get; set; }
        public glocation location { get; set; }
        public string location_type { get; set; }
        public gviewport viewport { get; set; }
    }

    public class gviewport
    {
        public glocation northeast { get; set; }
        public glocation southwest { get; set; }
    }

    public class glocation
    {
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lng { get; set; }
    }
```